# Delete all files in a folder but skip files that cointain certain string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to clean the temp files, but I want skip some files that cointain a certain name. No matter the extension it is.

Tried this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "eol=: delims="  %F in ('dir "%windir%/temp" /b /a-d * ') do find "TESTE" %F > nul || del "%F"
pause
```

Wanted all files that cointains `TESTE` in name got skipped from deletation.

But my script not even run.

Can someone explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Try `do type "%F" | find "TESTE" || del "%F"` and also fix the command, do `\ ` instead of `/` like `'dir "%windir%\temp" /b /a-d * '` if this is a batch file you have to double the percents like so: `%%F`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not absolutely clear whether you want to exclude files from deletion whose names or whose contents include a certain string; anyway, this is for the former:

```cmd
pushd "%WinDir%\TEMP" && (
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D "*.*" ^| findstr /V /I /C:"TESTE"
    ') do (
        ECHO del /F "%%F"
    )
    popd
)
```

Once you are satisfied with the output, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` command**.

---

The above script would also not delete files whose extensions contain the given string. But if you want to regard only the base name, you might want to use this code instead:

```cmd
pushd "%WinDir%\TEMP" && (
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D "*.*"
    ') do (
        set "NAME=%%~nF"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if /I "!NAME:TESTE=!"=="!NAME!" (
            endlocal
            ECHO del /F "%%F"
        ) else endlocal
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: please check my `Edit 1`

Comment: @BlackMamba, corrected my second script to *not* delete matching files; moreover, I rolled back your edit as it actually constitutes a new question (deleting sub-directories), which you should have asked in a new post (preferrably linking to this one); you should not change or extend the scope of a question, particularly when there are already answers, beause they appear incomplete then…

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `findstr.exe` with its `/V` and `/M` options to list your unwanted files.

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VPMLI "TESTE" "%SystemRoot%\TEMP\*" 2^>NUL'
)Do @Del /A/F "%%G"
@Pause
```

Please note that the `\Windows\Temp` directory is usually protected, so you may need to run this script 'as administrator'.