# Delete files, folders and sub-folders but skipping files that cointain certain string

Tags: batch-file

Just tried to clean the temp folder of Windows and it inside folders, skipping all files that contains `TESTE` in it name.

```
@echo off
pushd "%WinDir%\TEMP" && (
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        dir /B /A:-D "*.*"
    ') do (
        set "NAME=%%~nF"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if /I "!NAME:TESTE=!"=="!NAME!" (
            endlocal
            del /F /Q "%%F"
            rd /F /S /Q "%%F"               
            md %windir%\temp
        ) else endlocal
    )
    popd
)
```

It's say that `F` is wrong to deleting the folder.

This is a complement of this question: [Delete all files in a folder but skip files that cointain certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460468/delete-all-files-in-a-folder-but-skip-files-that-cointain-certain-string)

Comment: What is your issue? Have you opened a Command Prompt window, typed `rd /?`, pressed `[ENTER]`, and read the usage information for the command `RD`? Did you see a `/F` option? Also, how do you expect `%%F` to ever be a directory name, when you've specified only files as your resulting `%%F` variables? Also are you wanting to remove all subdirectories? or only those which don't contain files which contain your target string?

Comment: Yes, i didn't open it. Truth, `F` doesn't exist. Anyway on my mind `%%F` will make `rd` delete folders skipping these files.

Comment: I wanted it remove all files, directories and sub-directories skipping ONLY files that contain `TESTE` in it name. If a sub-directory has 3 files and one of than has `TESTE` in it name, it have to delete the others 2. If these 3 files doesn't have `TESTE` in it name, delete the whole folder. The meaning is that: Delete all files and sub-folders but keep files that cointain a certain string.

Comment: @Compo also i'm curious, how's Fred?

Comment: Your last pertinent statement has made it less clear again. Are you wanting to have only files whose name contains `TESTE` in the Temp directory? or do you also want any subdirectories with files whose names contain `TESTE`? Fred's as strong as an Ox!

Comment: I want also subdirectories with files whose names contain `TESTE` be keeped.

Comment: I'm glad Fred is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rd` command does not feature an `/F` option.

Anyway, here is how I would modify the script to achieve your goal of keeping all files with the string `TESTE` in their base names, even in sub-directories (if I got it right):

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Change into the target directory:
pushd "%WinDir%\TEMP" && (
    rem // Loop through all files in the target directory, recursing into sub-directories:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        dir /S /B /A:-D "*.*"
    ') do (
        rem // Store the base name of the current file:
        set "NAME=%%~nF"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Check whether the base name of the current file contains the string `TESTE`:
        if /I "!NAME:TESTE=!"=="!NAME!" (
            rem // Sub-string `TESTE` not encountered, so do some stuff at this point:
            endlocal
            rem // Delete the current file:
            del /F /Q "%%F"
            rem // Attempt to delete its parent directory when it is empty:
            rd "%%F\.." 2> nul
        ) else endlocal
    )
    rem // Return fro the target directory:
    popd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic untested single line [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) example, which may be sufficient for your purposes:

```batch-file
@"%__APPDIR__%Robocopy.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp" "%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp" "*TESTE*.*" /S /Move 1> NUL
```

*This will most likely require to be run elevated, due to your directory being a protected OS location.*

Comment: Nice idea! Good job! Liked the `move` idea to keep only the string i want!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @BlackMamba! Why, might I ask, would you prefer a seven line script over a faster single line one? *The only potential difference I can see is that this could possibly keep directories with names containing `TESTE` too!*

Comment: It's fine! I already voted this question. Anyway what really matter is bth questions here for everyone see the possibilities. Thank you!